# Mule deployment throws zip file closed error

Tags: ant, mule

I am trying to deploy mule project which was built using ant task mulePackage to mule ee runtime 3.1.1. However, I get the following error. The same code works when I start my project as a mule app directly from eclipse IDE with Mule plugin. I tried rebuilding the app. The content of zip also seems to be correct. But the error persists.Any suggestions please..

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:416)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:161)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:208)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:191)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:757)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:735)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:146)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:385)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1002)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1192)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SecuritySupport$6.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Able to get to the actual error, below:**

```
   java.io.IOException: Unable to load resource xslt/convertrequest.xsl
at org.mule.util.IOUtils.getResourceAsString(IOUtils.java:54)
      ....
```

My code for xsl reference:

```
<xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xslt/convertrequest.xsl">
</xm:xslt-transformer>
```

The xsl file is in xslt folder which is under classes in the zip. I have seen couple of similar problems,but they were with the reference of xslt from a jar file. My case is different, it has all the xslts within the mule app zip file. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting from studio instead of using ant.

Comment: I dont have that option. I am doing it from eclipse and cant find a suitable plugin for mule version 3.1.

Comment: Download mule ce and import your project. Its just an option.

Comment: @Rinkesh..thanks for the suggestion, I would have done that first up if there an option. Unfortunately there appears no studio for this version of mule.

Comment: It still appears to be a problem. I intermittently get this error. The problem seems to be of xsl reference. I have mutiple files using the xsl and I have clubbed all the xsls into one file and trying to refer them.